# how to list an object arguments in python?

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(url = "url", username = "myusername", password = "mysecretpassword")
```

Is it possible to get the argument of the password parameter from the **db** object?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to, but no you can't. You can read the [mysql.connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysql-connector.html) documentation and see that it does not expose the password as an attribute.

You could also run `dir(db)` to see what it supports.